# Application Insights QuickPulseTelemetryModule generating lots of Scheduled Tasks. What could be causing this?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, azure-application-insights

In the process of trying to diagnose slowdowns in a Web Application, I've come across a lot of Tasks in the VS Task Window that are shown as "Scheduled".

I narrowed this down to Application Insights QuickPulseTelemetryModule which is calling Task.Delay on a background thread every 5 seconds. In the screenshot I see a new Scheduled Task being created every 5 seconds that never seems to run. The list of these tasks just grows and grows and grows.

I'm not an expert on Task scheduling but to me this doesn't seem right, so the question is, is this expected behaviour? If it's not, what could be the issue here? Could this be the result of something within my application?

The code in the screenshot is the line in QuickPulseTelemetry module that is invoking Task.Delay (not my code).

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code that is calling their code?

Comment: There isn't any. The ApplicationInsights packages are installed via nuget and there's a appliationinsights.config where the module is added under a TelemetryModules section.

Comment: This code will have at most one Task.Delay in flight (the next one will not start till the previous completes).

Comment: @ZakiMa agree, but the tasks window shows a mountain of tasks all in "scheduled" state, each one generated by the Task.Delay call (I've confirmed this through debugging)

Comment: Yep. Not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: is there something creating many instances of the quickpulse module, each with one task?

Comment: @JohnGardner I don't believe so, the module is initialised by the applicationinsights.config file, we don't manually load anything. I downloaded and built a debug build of the AI module and it only gets instantiated once. Each time the loop executes the Task.Delay statement a task is left in the "Scheduled" state